# "Pinning" a question tag?

Tags: support

Sorry if this has asked before but I wasn't even sure how to search for it

Basically I was wondering - can I "pin" my favorite tag(s) so that every time I click on "Questions" that tag is automatically used/enabled?

Comment: Try clicking on your favorite tag then adding a bookmark.

Comment: That's probably a good way to do tackle it I guess :P I just assumed there was a way inline that I was missinh

Comment: You could try searching [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/).  Someone might have made a script that does what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah I'll give that go and see

Comment: You may want to check on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814/218565. Currently I initially arrive from a google search for my largest tag, and it happens by magic.